# user input character evaluation to constant character

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I am trying to complete my guessing game here but the program would just crash when the user has input the correct number
I intended to use `strcmpi` function to evaluate the user's choice but it seems not working. The way that I am doing is to use `c=getchar()` be compared with `'y'` or `'n'` directly. Somehow I get a bad feeling about it.
So if this is not the proper way to do it please tell me what is the correct approach.
Also I get a warning says that

> implicit declaration of function 'strcmpi

as I build it. Then I did try to add `#include <string.h>` and it pops out more errors indicating me that for example

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmpi' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]|
>   note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'

Any help would be appreciated and here is my program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_NUMBER 100

int main(void) {
int randNum;
srand((int)time(0));
randNum = rand() % 100 + 1;

long guessNum;
int count = 0;

do {
    printf("\nplz enter a guess from integer 1 to 100: %d", randNum);
    scanf("%ld", &guessNum);

    if(scanf("%ld", &guessNum)==1)
        {

    if (guessNum < randNum && guessNum >= 1) {
        printf("your guess is lower than the selected number");
        count++;
        printf("\nyou have %d times left to try", 100 - count);
    }
    if (guessNum > randNum && guessNum <= 100) {
        printf("your guess is higher than the selected number");
        count++;
        printf("\nyou have %d times left to try", 100 - count);
    }
    if (guessNum < 1 || guessNum > 100) {
        printf("your guess is out of the range, plz pick between 1-100");
        count++;
        printf("\nyou have %d times left to try", 100 - count);
    }
    if (guessNum == randNum) {
            count++;
        printf("congrats you got the right answer, you used %d times to make the right     guess", count
               );

        printf("\nwould you like to have another round? (y/n)\n");

        char c;
        c = getchar();


        if(strcmpi(c, 'y') == 0)
            {
                count = 0;
            printf("plz enter an integer from 1 - 100: ");
            scanf("%ld", &guessNum);
            }
            else if(strcmpi(c, 'n') == 0)
                {
                    printf("the game is ended!");
            break;
                    }else
                    {
                     printf("plz enter either y or n!");
                        }

            }

            }
            else
            {
            printf("plz enter a valid integer from 1 - 100: \n");
            char c;
            while((c = getchar())!= '\n');
            count++;
            printf("\nyou have %d times left to try", 100 - count);
            }
            } while (count < MAX_NUMBER);
            printf("\nthe guess time is used out!");

            return 0;
            }
```

Comment: `strcmpi()` isn't a function, and this code can't even compile. Perhaps you meant `stricmp()`? Please submit an example which compiles.  Also, read up on it, you can't pass a char constant such as 'n' to that function - you need to pass a string (such as "n").  Also, you are reading the user input char with getchar, so perhaps you shout just say, `if( c == 'n' )` instead.

Comment: @JohnH - `strcmpi()` and `stricmp()` are synonymous in some libraries, notably Microsoft. But as you say `if (c=='n')` would do the job.

Comment: `while((c = getchar())!= '\n');` is a infinite loop should `stdin` close.  Better to do `int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`

Comment: Code likely fails if the first guess is correct as the following `c = getchar();` consumes the `'\n'`.

Comment: Another thing if you ever need to be portable, `stricmp` doesn't exist on UNIX systems... the POSIX function for doing this is called `strcasecmp()`

Comment: @chux the program would just crash whenever a right guess is detected.

Comment: @JohnH - Thanks for the note! I haven't tried it on UNIX systems yet but I will keep in mind of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcmpi()` operates on strings of characters, but `getchar()` retrieves only a single character.

You either need to do something like this:

```
// make a string for comparison
char s[2]={0};
s[0]=getchar();
if (strcmpi(s, "y")==0)
{
 //etc
}
```

or this:

```
// compare single character
char c=0;
c=getchar();
if (c=='y')
{
 // etc
}
```

Comment: `strcmpi`?  Is that a variant of `strcmp`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits - case-insensitive string compare. Exactly the same as `stricmp`. OP doesn't really need it for what he's doing ...!

Comment: @snowcrash09 yep I actually don't necessarily need that expression with your second way above. 
But do you know why the program would skip the `y/n` evaluation after the user input a correct guess? I can't see where the problem is..

Comment: @snowcrash09 - After make a right guess, it jumped into last scenario said `plz enter either y or n!` instead of reading the user's input and started over from the top. It is so weird..

Comment: Note: Unless the return value from `getchar()` is saved as an `int`, proper EOF detection is challenging.  Simplest to `int c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) Handle_Closed_stdin(); if (c=='y') ...`